# Have the coordinates, how to set the specific region?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I created an application which shows latitude and longitude position where is device. My question is how can I create something like IF method, that will show for example: If I'm between 46° and 48° longitude, and 52 and 54 latitude; program shows "This is the region 1!"
example 2: I'm between 54° and 56° longitude, and 59° and 61° latitude; program shows "This is the region 2!" and so on...  Any advices? Thanks a lot!
here is the java code:

```
    public class dvica extends Activity implements LocationListener{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView location;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String Latitude,Longitude;
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.dvica);
location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst1);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location lokacija1) {
location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
location.setText("Latitude:" + lokacija1.getLatitude() + ", "
        + "Longitude:" + lokacija1.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int stanje, Bundle extras) {
Log.d("Latitude","status");
}

}
```

Comment: Where do you get the region boundaries from (i.e. lat_from 46 lat_to 48...) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question? I don't understand.. :/  I am looking for boundaries, I'd like to set them by myself...if you know what I mean.

Comment: You say you want to check which region user is in. From where do you get the regions? I don't know how I can be any more clear :)

Comment: Oh sorry, now I understand :P well, this is the part of the question too :P  I don't know where and how to set them..but do I need the boundaries, or I can create them with this method automatically? :/  i.e. lat_from 46 lat_to 48 is region 1- you're in region 1

Comment: Look..if latency is between 46 and 48, and longitude between 52 and 54,  location.setText("you're in region 1"); can't I do that just something simple like this? :/

Comment: Mate, can you help me please? I'm really stuck with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using such multiple if statements just looks bad and is not the most efficient way, but if that floats your boat then sure:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location lokacija1) {
    location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst1);

    double lat = lokacija1.getLatitude();
    double lng = lokacija1.getLongitude();

    if (lat > 52 && lat < 54 && lon > 46.0 && lon < 48.0) {
        location.setText("Region 1");
    } else if (lat > 54 && lat < 56 && lon > 48.0 && lon < 50.0) {
        location.setText("Region 2");
    } else {
        location.setText("Unrecognized region");
    }

    Log.d("TAG", String.format("lat:%.4f lon:%.4f", lat, lng));
}
```